# wordpress site work on local but not works on online server

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress, wordpress-theming

my wordpress site correctly working on local server but when i am uploading it on server 404 page not found error is showing.

i check my index.php its correctly redirecting.
here is code:-

```
      <?php

       define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

       /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
         require('./wp-blog-header.php');
             ?>
```

i check my wp-blog-header.php,its also working.because i forward it to phpinfo page and info page showing,but site page not showing.
here is wp-blog-header code:-

```
             if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

       $wp_did_header = flase;

  require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

wp();

//wp_redirect( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-

          loader.php' , 301 );
                    // exit;
                require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
          }
          ?>
```

and my temp-loader.php is:-

```
       <?php
      /**
     * Loads the correct template based on the visitor's url
        * @package WordPress
       */
    if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
do_action('template_redirect');

     // Halt template load for HEAD requests. Performance bump. See #14348
       if( 'HEAD' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && apply_filters( 'exit_on_http_head', true ) )
exit();

       // Process feeds and trackbacks even if not using themes.
       if ( is_robots() ) :
do_action('do_robots');
return;
    elseif ( is_feed() ) :
do_feed();
return;
       elseif ( is_trackback() ) :
include( ABSPATH . 'wp-trackback.php' );
return;
         endif;

    if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES ) :
$template = false;
if     ( is_404()            && $template = get_404_template()            ) :
elseif ( is_search()         && $template = get_search_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_tax()            && $template = get_taxonomy_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()     ) :
elseif ( is_home()           && $template = get_home_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_attachment()     && $template = get_attachment_template()     ) :
    remove_filter('the_content', 'prepend_attachment');
elseif ( is_single()         && $template = get_single_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_page()           && $template = get_page_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_category()       && $template = get_category_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_tag()            && $template = get_tag_template()            ) :
elseif ( is_author()         && $template = get_author_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_date()           && $template = get_date_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_archive()        && $template = get_archive_template()        ) :
elseif ( is_comments_popup() && $template = get_comments_popup_template() ) :
elseif ( is_paged()          && $template = get_paged_template()          ) :
else :
    $template = get_index_template();
endif;
if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) )
    include( $template );
return;
       endif;
         ?>
```

and my htaccess file is:-

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
      RewriteEngine on
         # BEGIN WordPress
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
        # END WordPress


    # PROTECT WP-CONFIG 
        <Files wp-config.php> 
           order Allow,Deny 
          Deny from all
           </Files>
```

plz tell me how i run my site online.

Comment: one thing more   when i remove "if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', 

$template ) )"   this code from templat-loader.php my code runs but not formated,if i write this condition code not works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really frustrating problem when using WordPress indeed. But I'll try to share some experiences I had.

0) [**Enable debugging mode**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress): In wp-config.com change WP_DEBUG to TRUE and add the following lines:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

With this, we'll have WP showing up more errors than we want ;)

*tip: use it in local machine to make a bulletproof plugin/theme/project*

1) **Check if the 404 is from the default browser or from wordpress**: Try to access wp-admin url. This is a good way to check if the domain is properly set. Sometimes the error is that index.php is not being found, so, we need to load something that will not care for the plugins and themes, that's the reason I suggest to use the wp-admin.

*tip: Even a theme-less install, will have the wp-admin working*

2) **Remove anything that can be the problem**: If we can't find exactly what's wrong on previous steps, we need to get dirty: rename the **THEMES** and **PLUGINS** folders to ensure that the problem isn't any of the plugins.

*tip: sometimes a blank line in the beginning of a plugin file can break completly your project*

3) **Give a link**: I can't comment yet, but I'll be glad on helping you if you send me a link to see the error.

Comment: hi,Thanks for your help,sorry but i am new in word press.by your suggestion i see error message on my browser. but dont know how i correct this,will you please help me again,   here is error message :---------------------------Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.   this message is in function.php

Comment: and one more thing which i forget to tel you is my wp-admin is also working but site not working

Comment: good one i deactivate woocommerse check-out manager plugin and all eroors gone,but again its showing "The requested page cannot be displayed" error.now whats happen?

Comment: Error 403 means permission denied (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) so it means: files with wrong permissions.

Comment: problem found.problem in my theme. sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

While migrating wordpress site from local server to Live server.
There are following steps we need to take into account:

1. **Database configuration that is in wp-config.php**
2. **site url**: if you are developing woocommerce site then manually we can change site url in whole database. so there is better solution that **search and replace** script.
   to avoid 404 issue.
3. **Put this script in root folder and replace old url with new url.**