# Cannot access Wordpress dashboard through WAMP

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I can access the actual wordpress site via WAMP's localhost route, but I cannot log into the admin/dashboard page of the wordpress site.

I think it is a problem with apache.

Can anybody help me?

here are messages from the apache error logs:

```
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:17.294107 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2700:tid 416] AH00422:   Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:19.296221 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5784:tid 324] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:19.328223 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2700:tid 416] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5784 exited successfully.
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:22.842424 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5408:tid 416] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:22.842424 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5408:tid 416] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:22.842424 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5408:tid 416] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:22.844424 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5408:tid 416] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4348
[Sun Nov 03 07:11:24.173500 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4348:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

More info:
The error is not a 404. Rather wordpress doesnt recognize my username/password.

final edit:

found a solution to my problem:
http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-a-wordpress-database/

Comment: What do you mean you cant access it? Do you get a 404? Can you get to sub pages on the wordpress site, not just the homepage?

Comment: Rename the folder `plugins` to `plugins-old`, this will disable all plugins and much probably allow admin access.

Comment: I suggest this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913069/wordpress-site-work-on-local-but-not-works-on-online-server/18913367#18913367 .
It has some tricks for debugging wordpress.